# Toggling expand/collapse button for a knockout table/sub- table

Tags: html, typescript, knockout.js

I have a table using Knockout and Typescript.  Each record on the table is expandable with an expand button.  Clicking this expand button toggles the collapse button. The problem I'm having is that when there are more than 1 records in the table, clicking this expand button toggles the collapse button for all of the records in the table.  Is there anyway to just toggle the one I've clicked? Here's the code:

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'id': 'show_' + $index()}">
                    <img src="../../Images/expand.gif" class="expand_button" alt="Show Checks" title="Show Checks" border="0" data-bind="click: PrintCheck.GetBankDrafts, visible: !$parent.expand(), click: PrintCheck.ToggleExpand">
                    <img src="../../Images/collapse.gif" class="collapse_button" alt="Show Checks" title="Show Checks" border="0" data-bind="visible: $parent.expand(), click: PrintCheck.ToggleExpand">
                </a>
```

The Typescript

```
class SearchPrintedChecksModel {
    public expand = ko.observable(false);
    public checkRuns = ko.observableArray<CheckRunModel>(null);
 }

  $(document).ready(() => {
    ko.applyBindings(printModel);
});


var printModel = new SearchPrintedChecksModel();

export function ToggleExpand(data: CheckRunModel): void {
    printModel.expand(!printModel.expand());
    GetBankDrafts(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want each table to keep track of its own expanded state. Your toggle variable appears to be global with respect to the tables so it's getting globally applied to all of them.

First you'll have to have a separate observable for each table to keep track of their respective expanded states. Move the expand variable from SearchPrintedChecksModel to the model for your table (CheckRunModel?). Then in your ToggleExpand function change printModel.expand(...) to data.expand(...). Finally in your binding change "visible: $parent.expand()" to just "visible: expand".